# How can I get my nested ng-repeat form inputs to stop updating each other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### My input fields are updating each other!

There's clearly some pass-by-reference shenanigans here, but I can't figure it out.

I have a custom directive that I'm setting up with ng-repeat:

```
<my-dir ng-repeat="obj in mio" obj="obj" other="otro" unique-name="_{{$index}}"></my-dir>
```

This directive contains a form whose inputs are *also* ng-repeating directives. (Each instance of the form needs the same set of inputs.)

Things I have done:

- Given each `my-dir` form and each input element within it a unique `id`
- Tried to use [a composite `track by`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232122/ng-repeat-with-track-by-over-multiple-properties) in the nested `ng-repeat` (i.e. `track by uniqueName + input.varname`), but couldn't seem to pass in variables from the parent scope
- Wrapped the nested `ng-repeat` in an `ng-if` to see if that created a convenient isolate scope

My input fields are still updating each other.

#### Additional code

in `my-dir.html`:

```
<form name="{{uniqueName}}">
  <parameter-directive
    ng-repeat="input in otro.inputs"
    type="input.vartype"
    name="input.varname"
    id-key="{{uniqueName}}"
    ng-model="input">
  </parameter-directive>
</form>
```

and in `parameter-directive.html`:

```
<label for="{{name}}" class="pull-left">{{name}}</label>
<input
  ng-required="{{defaultValue == null}}"
  id="{{idKey + '_' + name}}"
  ng-model="ngModel.val"
  ng-attr-type="{{inputType}}"
>
```

(Happy to also include code from the directive `js`, but this question is already quite long.)

Comment: Please provide a working example on some sandbox online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue had nothing to do with the directives lacking unique ids.

The issue was that the `parameter-directive`'s `ng-model` was bound to the same object from the parent directive (in the example above, the object passed in with `other="otro"`) and passed by reference.

The `otro` object also happens to be loaded from an API, so I ended up adding a `broadcast` event:

in `my-dir.directive.js`:

```
$scope.getOtro = function getOtro() {
  $http.get(URL)
    .then((resp) => {
      $scope.otro = resp.data;
      $scope.$broadcast('otro-loaded', $scope.otro.inputs);
      }
  };
```

in `parameter-directive.directive.js`:

```
$scope.$on('otro-loaded', (_, inputs) => {
    $scope.inputs = angular.copy(inputs);
});
```

I will not claim that this is a particularly *elegant* way to solve this problem, but it did the trick.